# RegEx \D matches start and end of line as well

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to find lines that are 3 digits and 3 other characters: I thought I use the following RegEx:

```
^\d{3}\D{3}$
```

But take the following sample text file and run the RegEx above (the text must have the empty lines in it):

```
1
12
123xxx
123y


aaabb
```

The problem is that there are two matches: 123xxx (which is fine), but also 123y is matched!
I suspect the reason is that "y" + the end-of-line + the beginning-of-next-line are also matched.

How can I tell the regex engine to ignore line beginnings and endings with \D and match characters only, not positions?

Comment: What are you using to execute this regular expression against the text?

Comment: I'm using UltraEdit at the moment

Comment: Check the "Match Whole Word Only" checkbox.  That should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `$` in UltraEdit changes depending on whether you have "Match Whole Word Only" checked or not.  To get the behavior you want you need to make sure that that option is checked.  Your regular expression doesn't need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
/^\d{3}\D{3}$/m
```

The `m` means

> Treat string as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start or end of the string to matching the start or end of any line anywhere within the string.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

I don't know about UltraEdit exactly but I expect it will have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
^\d{3}[\S]{3}$
```

Match lines with 3 digits followed by three characters that are not blank characters.